# use loop to read math expression, separate numbers

Tags: java, loops, stack

I am trying to use a stack structure to convert infix to postfix expression. Is there a way using for-loop to read numbers from the input String?

For example if the input is (23+9)*2. I developed a method to check if charAt(i) is +, -, * or /. I checked the first char '(' and push it on to the stack. And then I want to read 23 as one number, and add it to the String postfix. `If ( ! isOperator(charAt(i))`, then what should I do? How can I do it using a loop? Many thanks!

```
for (int j=0;j<input.length();j++){
            char ch= input.charAt(j);             
            if(!isOperator){
                if (ch=='('){
                    s.push();

                }else{//if it's a number i.e.23, it should be attached to string post as 23, instead of 2 and 3,
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `StringBuilder` to add characters to:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int j=0;j<input.length();j++){
  char ch= input.charAt(j);             
  if(!isOperator(ch)){
    if (ch=='('){
      // process contents of builder.toString(), if any, then reset builder
      s.push();
    } else {
      builder.append(ch);
    }
  } else {
    // process contents of builder.toString(), if any, then reset builder
  }
```

Comment: +1 You need to check for ')' as well. As per the above code, it will be added to the builder.

Comment: @Priyesh Yes, that's true. I'm assuming the OP will use my code example as inspiration rather than an actual solution.

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to make sure the OP does not miss the closing bracket :-).